# Return JQuery.When deferred resolved

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a function that include a function to an async function, but I need to return the first one when the async call has been resolved. I'm trying using

```
return JQuery.when()
```

The following function is a resume.

```
function getData(x){
 if (x = 1){
    return JQuery.when(asynFunction().then(function (data){
        (...);
        return;
    });
 }
 else {
  (...)
  return;
 }

}
```

The objective is that getData() doesn't return until the async call has finished.
Any idea?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: maybe you can wrap the jQuery.when method inside a function?
return function() { jQuery.when(...)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `asynFunction()` returns a Promise, `getData` might, at its simplest, look like this :

```
function getData(x) {
    if (x = 1) {
        return asynFunction();
    }
    else {
        var myValue = 'whatever';
        return myValue;
    }
}
```

However it's often better (though not absolutely necessary) to arrange for a function to return a Promise in all circumstances. This guarantees that wherever `getData()` is called, the result can be handled in an asynchronous manner (ultimately with `.then` or `.done()`) even if it is synchronously derived.

```
function getData(x) {
    if (x = 1) {
        return asynFunction();
    }
    else {
        ...
        var myValue = 'whatever';
        return jQuery.when(myValue);
    }
}
```